# What's the opposite of .flex-fill in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Following the documentation here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#fill

I want a flex element to fill only on devices smaller than sm (which lines up with my column breakpoint in the example)

So, I would use something like `.flex-fill .flex-sm-nofill`

But there's no such thing as `flex-nofill`!

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but how I can solve my problem using only vanilla bootstrap classes?

I understand it wouldn't be hard to create this new `-nofill` class, but I just wanted to know if there's already a solution and I just couldn't figure it out.

Code Example, in this case the elements I want to fill are the Buttons :

```
<div class="row justify-content-between p-3">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-xl-6 pb-2">
    <select class="custom-select" id="layer_select">
        <option data-dismiss="modal" value="0">Option1</option></select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-sm-end">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2 flex-fill flex-sm-nofill"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary flex-fill flex-sm-nofill"><i class="material-icons">filter_list</i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle (Mess with the width to see the effect) : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/155315/

I want the buttons to have fixed width when they're side by side with the select.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`flex-fill` sets `flex: 1 1 auto`.
In order to change this for the `sm` breakpoint, you can set `flex-sm-grow-0`.
Then you'll have `flex: 0 1 auto`.

See [Grow and Shrink](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink).

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v36/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row justify-content-between p-3">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-xl-6 pb-2">
    <select class="custom-select" id="layer_select">
     <option data-dismiss="modal" value="0">Option1</option></select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-sm-end">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2 btn-icon flex-fill flex-sm-grow-0"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-icon flex-fill flex-sm-grow-0"><i class="material-icons">filter_list</i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Bootstrap 5, responsive breakpoints for flex-fill is available.

"Responsive variations also exist for flex-fill.

.flex-fill
.flex-sm-fill
.flex-md-fill
.flex-lg-fill
.flex-xl-fill
.flex-xxl-fill"

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#fill

In your case .flex-md-fill will work.

```
<div class="row justify-content-between p-3">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-xl-6 pb-2">
    <select class="custom-select" id="layer_select">
        <option data-dismiss="modal" value="0">Option1</option></select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between justify-content-sm-end">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2 flex-md-fill"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary flex-md-fill"><i class="material-icons">filter_list</i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```